# how can I handle values which have commas in csv?

Tags: java, csv

I am uysing javacsv API to write the value to a .csv file.So one of my column "ID's" has values 7,2,3,4 .Now usually when the csv file finds a comma it shifts the value to the next column.So to avoid that I have used:

String d= "\"" +s + "\""; where s is the string that has the values in the column.But even if I do this the value are still shiftes to the next column and the column has  quotes in it.I also read in one of the post that import the same in notepad and the  try opening it with excel, so I have followed that and it worked fine but the commas are not there. I want the value to appear in the same format as it comes from the database like 7,2,3,4. I have gone through many posts and they suggested to use CSV API's and I am using javacsv which uses Csv Writer but no luck. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look int the [`setEscapeMode`](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html#setEscapeMode%28int%29) method on `CSVReader`.

Something like `reader.setEscapeMode(CsvReader.ESCAPE_MODE_BACKSLASH)` ought to set the reader so that it regards a backslash as an escape.

Comment: So before I do csvWriter.output do I have to call the CsvReader for that backslash??